# nltk.DecisionTreeClassifier.train doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, decision-tree

I am attempting to run the following code which was provided as an example in the following book chapter: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html [see 1.4 Part-of-Speech Tagging]

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

#
suffix_fdist = nltk.FreqDist()
for word in brown.words():
    word = word.lower()
    suffix_fdist[word[-1:]] += 1
    suffix_fdist[word[-2:]] += 1
    suffix_fdist[word[-3:]] += 1

common_suffixes = [suffix for (suffix,count) in suffix_fdist.most_common(100)]
print(common_suffixes)

def pos_features(word):
    features={}
    for suffix in common_suffixes:
        features['endswith({})'.format(suffix)] = word.lower().endswith(suffix)
    return features

tagged_words = brown.tagged_words(categories='news')
featuresets = [(pos_features(n), g) for (n,g) in tagged_words]

size = int(len(featuresets)*0.1)
train_set, test_set = featuresets[size:], featuresets[:size]

classifier = nltk.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(train_set)
nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
```

When I run the code IDLE seems to go into an infinite loop. The problem appears to occur within the nltk.DecisionTreeClassifier.trai method call. Any idea why this is happening and how I might go about fixing it would be highly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem today while I was trying, as far as I understood it is related with our computation power when I ran the code with less data I got a result back.

`classifier = nltk.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(train_set[86000:])`